# Trigonometric functions in symbolic tolbox MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am trying to solve a system of two equations that contain trigonometric equations in Matlab using the Symbolic toolbox

My equations are:

```
syms Xb Xg L X2 X1 theta costheta Yb Yg  
- Xb + Xg + X2 * cos(theta) + L* cos(theta + X1) == 0
- Yb + Yg + X2 * sin(theta) + L* sin(theta + X1) == 0
```

and I wan to solve this system for X1 and X2.

I try for starters to solve just  the first and I keep getting the warning: " Warning: Explicit solution could not be found."

It is not possible to get a solution when the  variable is in a trigonometric function like sin, cos etc?

The code for just the first is:

```
syms Xb Xg L X2 X1 costheta Yb Yg
sol = solve(- Xb + Xg + X2 * cos(theta) + L* cos(theta + X1) == 0, X1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't check right now, but I think you want something like this

```
[X1,X2]=solve(-Xb+Xg+X2*cos(theta)+L*cos(theta+X1),-Yb+Yg+X2*sin(theta)+L*sin(theta+X1),X1,X2)
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, I had already done that. It returns:
X1 =[ empty sum ] and X2 =[ ]

Comment: Why do you have `costheta` in your symbolic initialisation line rather than `theta`?

Comment: You are right, in fact I had both cos(theta) and theta to test where the problem comes from.

Answer (score 0):

David's suggestion is working. Just tried it in Matlab R2013a. 
I only had to add

> syms theta

Comment: What do you get as a result?

Comment: the result is actually quite long so i couldn't post it as a comment. You can find it here: http://pastebin.com/t8ELJR2T